# Java: Erro ao passar referências em uma SuperType usando Converter Pattern para converter DTO/Entity

Tags: java, spring, java-ee

Estou fazendo um processo de serialização de uma classe DTO para Entity e vice versa. E para isso, eu uso um padrão de projeto denominado de *Converter Pattern*.

A princípio, criei uma classe genérica que realiza essas ações. veja:

```java
public abstract class Converter<DTO, ENTITY> {

    private final Function<DTO, ENTITY> fromDto;
    private final Function<ENTITY, DTO> fromEntity;

    public Converter(Function<DTO, ENTITY> fromDto, Function<ENTITY, DTO> fromEntity) {
        this.fromDto = fromDto;
        this.fromEntity = fromEntity;
    }

    public final ENTITY toEntity(final DTO dto) {
        return fromDto.apply(dto);
    }

    public final DTO toDto(final ENTITY entity) {
        return fromEntity.apply(entity);
    }

    public final List<ENTITY> toEntityList(final Collection<DTO> dtos) {
        return dtos.stream().map(this::toEntity).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public final List<DTO> toDtoList(final Collection<ENTITY> entities) {
        return entities.stream().map(this::toDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public final List<DTO> toDtoList(final Iterable<ENTITY> entities) {
        List<DTO> dtos = new ArrayList<>();
        entities.forEach(e -> dtos.add(toDto(e)));
        return dtos;
    }

}
```

E para usar, eu crio um serviço que consome este recurso estendendo esta classe, e passo como parâmetros da classe a DTO e a Entidade para estabelecer o processo de serialização. Veja um exemplo:

```java
@Service
public class DisciplinaConverter extends Converter<DisciplinaDto, DisciplinaEntity> {
    public DisciplinaConverter() {
        super(
                disciplinaDto -> new DisciplinaEntity(disciplinaDto.id, disciplinaDto.nome),
                disciplinaEntity -> new DisciplinaDto(disciplinaEntity.getId(), disciplinaEntity.getNome())
        );
    }
}
```

Até ai tudo bem, não são objetos customizados. Eu estou encontrando problema para renderizar realmente esses objetos. Veja um exemplo de erro que esta ocorrendo:

```java
@Service
public class TurmaConverter extends Converter<TurmaDto, TurmaEntity> {

    @Autowired
    private DisciplinaConverter disciplinaConverter;

    @Autowired
    private ProfessorConverter professorConverter;

    public TurmaConverter() {
        super(
            fromDto -> {
                TurmaEntity entity = new TurmaEntity();
                entity.setId(fromDto.id);
                entity.setDisciplina(disciplinaConverter.toEntity(fromDto.disciplina));
                entity.setProfessor(professorConverter.toEntity(fromDto.professor));
                return entity;
            },
            fromEntity -> new TurmaDto(
                fromEntity.getId(),
                professorConverter.toDto(fromEntity.getProfessor()),
                disciplinaConverter.toDto(fromEntity.getDisciplina())
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Quando tento converter uma os objetos ProfessoreDTO/ProfessorEntity e DisciplinaDto/DisciplinaEntity, acbo encontrando o erro:

`Cannot reference 'TurmaConverter.disciplinaConverter' before supertype constructor has been called`.

Como sair deste erro para converter meu objeto? Já tentei extrair, mas não tive ainda a solução.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o problema esteja ocorrendo porque você está utilizando atributos da classe no construtor e os atributos não foram injetados (via `@Autowired`) pelo Spring.

**Sugestões:**

1. Utilize uma biblioteca já pronta, testada e funcional que mapeia DTO / Entity, tal qual o [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/). Não vale a pena reinventar roda. [Com Spring Boot é mais simples ainda.](https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application)
2. Remova a lógica do construtor, optando por outro padrão (`FactoryPattern`, por exemplo). Não, sério, utilize o Model Mapper e seja feliz.

Comment: Grato pelos conselhos... sobre o conselho 1 é importante ainda avalia-lo por deibaixo dos panos. Pois o negócio não é reinventar a roda, e sim, deixar o sistema performatico. Eu não sei se modelmapper usa reflexão pode debaixo dos panos. E reflexão é um grande inimigo para a performance. Sobre o 2,  padrão que geralmente uso é o converter, mas vou ver a solução com o Factory. VLW!

Comment: Entendo, porém lembre-se de uma célebre frase: " Otimização prematura é a raiz de todo mal". Brincadeiras à parte, você pode optar pelo MapStruct, outra biblioteca de mapeamento, um pouco mais complexa de implementar, porém, uma das mais rápidas em vários benchmarks. Também trabalha bem com CDI. https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct